# Limiting one record to a Cypher COLLECTION

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am creating a messaging system and I would like the index page to show the top message of the people sending emails similar to most email and chat applications. Problem is I don't seem to be able to limit the results of the messages to just 1 and also to order the results by the 'created_at' date of the messages instead of the people who sent it.

My Cypher is:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:SENT]->(m:Message)-[:SENT_TO]->(op:Person{username:"the_username"})
WHERE NOT p.username = "the_username"
WITH p,m
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
RETURN DISTINCT p.first_name as first_name, 
                p.last_name as last_name, 
                p.username as username, 
                p.image_name as image_name,
                COLLECT({subject:m.subject, 
                         created_at:m.created_at, 
                         body:m.body, 
                         message_id:id(m),
                         status:m.status}) as message
```

I am looking to have the result produce the top message entered (by created_at property on the Message node) and then sort the results by the created_at property so the user can see the person who messaged them last.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only the most recent message from each person who send a message to the person with the desired username, you can use this slightly modified query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:SENT]->(m:Message)-[:SENT_TO]->(op:Person{username:"the_username"})
WHERE NOT p.username = "the_username"
WITH p,m
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
WITH p, (COLLECT(m))[0] AS m0
RETURN DISTINCT p.first_name as first_name, 
                p.last_name as last_name, 
                p.username as username, 
                p.image_name as image_name,
                COLLECT({subject:m0.subject, 
                         created_at:m0.created_at, 
                         body:m0.body, 
                         message_id:id(m0),
                         status:m0.status}) as message
```

The changes are:

1. This clause was added: `WITH p, (COLLECT(m))[0] AS m0`. This aggregates all the messages for each sender (in descending `created_at` order), and keeps just the first message, giving it the identifier "m0".
2. The subsequent clauses were changes to use "m0" instead of "m".

*Note: In #1, you could actually use `AS m` instead, which would allow you to avoid having to do #2. But, I chose to use a different identifier, to make the query easier to understand and maintain.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the way to limit the top item. Any ides on how to then order the people by who sent the message last?

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured out the rest and took the message out of the collection in the return and just added the user to the return with the message elements so I could sort it by message_id DESC

Comment: Just a thought: `HEAD(COLLECT(m))` might be more readable than `COLLECT(m)[0]`.